# Use fs.mkdir(path[, options], callback) without callback

Tags: javascript

I'm wondering if I want to use this function `fs.mkdir(path[, options], callback)` and I just want to create a directory and do nothing after... How do I do that? I see the callback is not optional. Is that when I would use `mkdirSync` ?

Callbacks are something I am struggling to learn. I know what they are but to implement them is another story.

Comment: it is optional, just do `fs.mkdir(somedir)` or `fs.mkdir(somedir,null)`, `fs.mkdir(somedir,false)` should also work

Comment: @FlashThunder Thank you for your response! I was under the impression only parameters surrounded by square brackets were optional

Comment: the way it works is that it checks if callback function is defined, and if it's a function after all, if not, it omits calling it, most (all properly implemented) of callbacks are working the same way

Answer (score 0):

Technically, it's possible to omit it (`mkdir` won't throw if that's the case), however, the documentation declared it as required, because **it's highly recommended to provide one, even if you don't use the result or do something after it**.

The reason of it is *error handling*.

Callback-based APIs cannot throw errors. Instead, they report errors through their callbacks. If the callback is absent, the error goes unhandled, and other processes expecting the folder to be created cannot be notified about the failure, that may cause further errors.